# Exclude folder from ng serve

Tags: angular

I have a folder `"project/src/Backend/*"` which I want to exclude from `ng serve`.
The Angular version is 6.1.x.

What I already tried is to add some excludes in *tsconfig.app.json*, *tsconfig.json* and *angular.json*.

Every solutions I found on www doesn't work for me.

*angular.json*

```
    {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "piloto": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/piloto",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/theme.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "piloto:build",
            
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "piloto:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "piloto:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**",
              "**/Backend/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "piloto-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "piloto:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "piloto:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "piloto"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The truth is that you should not have any back-end thing in front-end's src folder at all!**

But if you really want it, exclude the directory in src/tsconfig.app.json, not in angular.json.

Answer (score 1):

With `ng serve`, your project runs in a temporary development server which you won't use in production.

After you build the protect, only `/assests` will be served which is located in `{project-location}/dist/{project-name}/assets`.

So, you don't have to explicitly exclude other folders. But you can exclude it from integrating with the source code from `tsconfig.json` which is mostly not required.