# Angular cli 'ng serve' - exclude certain folders for auto-restart

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Angular CLI's `ng serve` auto-restarts when it detects changes in your project. Problem is, I'm locally testing a base64 image upload, and every time an image is converted and successfully uploaded to a subfolder in my project, Angular CLI starts recompiling my solution (because it detects new changes, the uploaded image)

Is it possible to exclude a subfolder from auto-restarting Angular?

Answer (score 0):

Try excluding the folder in the tsconfig.app.json

```
{
,
  "exclude": [
    // folder path
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57127864/exclude-folder-from-ng-serve