# Is there a possibility to exclude the video folder in angular?

Tags: angular

I have added some videos on my assets folder:

assets/video/video1.mp4

assets/video/video2.mp4

assets/video/video3.mp4

Problem, each time I make a change in dev mode (ng serve), it take lot of time to compile.

Have you an idea of a better solution?

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude folder from ng serve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57127864/exclude-folder-from-ng-serve)